# HA-Tomcat lags 1s on session initialization

Tags: java, tomcat, lag, high-availability

Why does tomcat lags 1.02 second on session-initialization?

Reproduce (Chrome):

1. Start Tomcat
2. Open Browser to http://localhost/ <-- takes 4 seconds, ok on initialization.
3. Close Browser
4. Open Browser, open debug console.
5. Browse to http://localhost/ <-- takes 1 second, NOT OK. [image: Not OK]
6. Close Browser
7. Debug Tomcat
8. Open Browser to http://localhost/
9. While loading: stop via debug. Looks like a native function blocking: [image]

Comment: What version of Tomcat?

Comment: What matters, its native code. Tomcat 7.0.30

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the JDK (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6978415?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) which is being addressed within TomCat with a hardcoded timeout set to 1 second.